# Selecting a folder by text under another folder using Selenium WebDriver [Java]

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I was working on automating testing using Selenium Webdriver.
But it got stuck at a point wherein I have to select a particular folder by name under another folder on a file manager.
Tried using findElements(By.tagName), (By.xpath) but unable to achieve the output.
Scenario
Its a file manager which has many folders, I have to select one and expand it which has many sub folders under it. Now i have to select particular sub folder by name by clicking a radio button next to it ??

Can anyone please help in as how to achieve it using selenium web driver in java ?

Comment: Adding part of HTML will be useful.

Comment: Is it a Tree structure in a webpage you are talking about..??